# No matching function for std::find() in eclipse. Works fine in XCode

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, vector

I"m running into an eclipse head scratcher.  I have trying to check to see if a certain string is in a std::vector called multiplayername.  I call

```
 if (std::find(multiplayernames.begin(), multiplayernames.end(), username) == multiplayernames.end())
{
//blah blah
}
```

to do it, which works perfectly find in XCode, but gives me a

```
no matching function for call to
'find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator,
std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::string&)
```

error in eclipse.  I assume this is an issue with how I have Eclipse set up.

Currently, I have

> APP_STL := gnustl_static

in the application.mk and I'm using ndk8b for both XCode and Eclipse. What else do I need to fix to get this working?

Comment: Have you included the necessary header files (namely `<algorithm>`, `<vector>`, `<string>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to include the header that declares `std::find`

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: /sigh.  I don't think I would have ever caught that on my own.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing a header. Now, implementations may indirectly include one header from another, which means that XCode can include a header even if you didn't do so explicitly.